# Display Wordpress Posts as gallery with title

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

for a project I am working on I have been trying to set up a wordpress post loop on a subpage which woould display all posts as a thumbnail image with the posts title underneath. However I do not get any posts listet but rather just one link referring to the subpage the gallery should be on. Could anyone help me out please?

Here is my code which is saved as page-gallery.php in my childthemes folder:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main" class="wrapper">
<?php global $query_string; if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="gallery_image_container">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <div class="gallery_image_thumb">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>
            </div>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The CSS is the following:

```
.gallery_container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 10px solid #CCC;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

I have created a jsfiddle to tell you what I want to achieve in the end: http://jsfiddle.net/vdpktLxr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code just echos the content of your page "page-gallery.php" . For displaying POSTS you need to use another loop, for example something like this:

```
 <?php
 // The Query
 query_posts( $args );

 // The Loop
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
     echo '<li>';
     the_title();
     echo '</li>';
 endwhile;

 // Reset Query
 wp_reset_query();
 ?>
```

You can find more info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I added the essential part into my answer. Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is working and looks exactly like I would want it! Between the two <li> echos I have now added "the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');" as well. The thing I would like to achieve now, is link these two items (image and title) to the post they come from. How would I do that? Is there an easier way than turning the css file into a php one like [this](http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/) and styling the li element?

Comment: Nevermind, I managed by just replacing "global $query_string;" through your suggested "query_posts( $args );" and adding the reset at the end. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You can link to the post by adding <a href="<?php the_permalink"></a>

Comment: Would be fine, when you accept my answer, when it worked for you :)